# Sizes of the dimensions of a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, c++17

I knew it but now can't remember the function template `std::???` that returns the sizes used for declaring a multidimensional arrays. Could you remind me this function? It works like in the below example, if I remember it right.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a[][2] = {{}, {}, {}};
  std::cout << std::size(a) << std::endl;    // outputs 3
  std::cout << std::???<0>(a) << std::endl;  // outputs 3, same as std::size(a)
  std::cout << std::???<1>(a) << std::endl;  // outputs 2, same as std::size(a[0])
}
```

I do not need its implementations, I want to use the existing function.

---

Thank @sklott the answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
  int a[][2] = {{}, {}, {}};
  std::cout << std::size(a) << std::endl;                        // outputs 3
  std::cout << std::extent<decltype(a), 0>::value << std::endl;  // outputs 3, same as std::size(a)
  std::cout << std::extent<decltype(a), 1>::value << std::endl;  // outputs 2, same as std::size(a[0])
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @sklott the answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
  int a[][2] = {{}, {}, {}};
  std::cout << std::size(a) << std::endl;                   // outputs 3
  std::cout << std::extent<decltype(a), 0>() << std::endl;  // outputs 3, same as std::size(a)
  std::cout << std::extent<decltype(a), 1>() << std::endl;  // outputs 2, same as std::size(a[0])
}
```